# Java Swing JPanel FlowLayout Height Issues

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jpanel

I'm busy writing a Java Swing GUI and I need two JPanes Side by Side.

I have a Single JPane that I am using as a Parent JPane which holds
two Child JPanes that are sitting side by side each one with a border
for separation.

Each Child JPane has a JPane inside with a GridBagLayout for
positioning elements. My code is as follows

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaGui extends JFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      JavaGui window = new JavaGui();

      // setup window here

      // main panels    

      JPanel container = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
      JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
      JPanel panelRight = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

      window.add(container);
      container.add(panelLeft);
      container.add(panelRight);

      // grid layout panels

      JPanel leftGrid = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      JPanel rightGrid = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();

      panelLeft.add(leftGrid);
      panelRight.add(rightGrid);

      // test labels

      JLabel label01 = new JLabel("Label 01");
      JLabel label02 = new JLabel("Label 02");
      JLabel label03 = new JLabel("Label 03");
      JLabel label04 = new JLabel("Label 04");

      // add labels to grids

      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 0;
      leftGrid.add(label01, grid);
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 0;
      rightGrid.add(label02, grid);
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 1;
      rightGrid.add(label03, grid);
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 2;
      rightGrid.add(label04, grid);

      // add borders to see sizes

      panelLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      panelRight.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

   };

};
```

This does what I expected however when I add borders to see the sizes of
my Left and Right Panels I see that they have different heights as
shown bellow when it is run

*CURRENT*

[image]

Is it possible to get these Panels to be the same height?

*REQUIRED*

[image]

Comment: Why are you using leftGrid and rightGrid wouldn't be simpler if you added your labels to panelLeft and panelRight directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try the following :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaGui extends JFrame {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      JavaGui window = new JavaGui();

      // setup window here

      // main panels    

      JPanel container = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
      JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      JPanel panelRight = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
      JPanel centralPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
      centralPanel.add(panelLeft);
      centralPanel.add(panelRight);
      window.add(container);
      container.add(centralPanel);

      // grid layout panels

      GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();


      // test labels

      JLabel label01 = new JLabel("Label 01");
      JLabel label02 = new JLabel("Label 02");
      JLabel label03 = new JLabel("Label 03");
      JLabel label04 = new JLabel("Label 04");

      // add labels to grids

      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 0;
      panelLeft.add(label01, grid);
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 0;
      panelRight.add(label02, grid);
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 1;
      panelRight.add(label03, grid);
      grid.gridx = 0;
      grid.gridy = 2;
      panelRight.add(label04, grid);

      // add borders to see sizes

      panelLeft.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      panelRight.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
      window.setVisible(true);
      window.pack();
   };

};
```

Comment: This is a good solution although I don't understand how it works

Comment: It's simple, when you want your components to be equal-size use the GridLayout, check the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).

Answer (score 2):

Create leftgrid and rightgrid using gridlayout with rows and columns parameters
JPanel leftGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
JPanel rightGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));`